How to define a non-terminal to represent 3 different data types in Bison?
The code generates this errors:
"ex1.y:435:33: error: request for member ‘ival’ in ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::fval’, which is of non-class type ‘float’435 | | TOK_INT_NUMBER { $$.ival = (int)$1; } // conversie la int si trebuie si la char * mai jos|                                 ^~~~
ex1.y:436:35: error: request for member ‘fval’ in ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::fval’, which is of non-class type ‘float’436 | | TOK_FLOAT_NUMBER { $$.fval = $1; }|                                   
                                            ^~
ex1.y:441:30: error: request for member ‘fval’ in ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::fval’, which is of non-class type ‘float’441 |                 $$.fval = ts->getFloatValue($ 1);|                                                              ^~~~  
ex1.y:443:30: error: request for member ‘ival’ in ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::fval’, which is of non-class type ‘float’443 |                 $$.ival = ts->getValue($1);"
I must say I did not touch the .h and .c files generated using the command "bison -d file.y".
In my snippet below, I want the non-terminal E to be able to represent int, float and char*, but it seems not to work.
`////////////////////////// beginning of TVAR class
class TVAR
{
    private:
    char*   nume;
    int     valoare;
    float   f_valoare;
    bool    is_float;
    TVAR*   next;

    public:
        static TVAR* head;
        static TVAR* tail;

        TVAR(char* n, int v = -1);
        TVAR(char* n, float v = -1);
        TVAR();

        int     exists(char* n);

        void    add(char* n, int v = -1);
        void    add_float(char* n, float v = -1);

        int     getValue(char* n);
        float   getFloatValue(char* n);

        void    setValue(char* n, int v);
        void    setFloatValue(char* n, float v);

        void    set_is_float(bool b) { is_float = b; }
        bool    get_is_float() { return is_float; }

        void    printVars();
};
////////////////////////// end of TVAR class


%union {
    float fval;
    int ival;
    char* sir;
}

%token <fval> TOK_FLOAT_NUMBER
%token <ival> TOK_INT_NUMBER
%token <sir> TOK_VARIABLE

%type <fval> E




E : TOK_INT_NUMBER { $$.ival = (int)$1; } // conversie la int si trebuie si la char * mai jos
| TOK_FLOAT_NUMBER { $$.fval = $1; }
| TOK_VARIABLE { 
        if (ts->exists($1))
        {
            if(ts->get_is_float() == true)
                $$.fval = ts->getFloatValue($1);
            else
                $$.ival = ts->getValue($1);
        } 
        else 
        {
            sprintf(msg,"%d:%d Eroare semantica: Variabila %s este utilizata fara sa fi fost declarata!", @1.first_line, @1.first_column, $1);
            yyerror(msg);
            YYERROR;
        }
    }
;`

I tried to make the non-terminal E represents float, int and char* by making E a float value (the more generic type of the three) and then casting to int or char* where needed.
I can't do this (Bison does not support it):
`%type <fval> E
%type <ival> E
%type <sir> E`


I've solved it.
Declare the union so:
union {struct{
char nume[100];
int valVariabila_int;
float valVariabila_float;
}VAR; char* sir; int ival; float fval; }
and the non-terminal E like this: %type  E.
Use valVariabila_float and valVariabila_float to access int and float members.
